# Kill multiple processes by name instead of pid

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a job that spins up 2-5 copies of a command on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I'm trying to figure out the simplest (i.e. single command-line instead of a script if possible) to `kill` all of them. The real trick is that I'm using [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html) to send ad-hoc commands across dozens of servers, that's why calling on each process is time consuming.

Example:

```
ps aux | grep bash 
user 1031 0.0 0.0  4444  652 ?      Ss  Aug15 0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/user/start-cacheable.bash
user 1032 0.0 0.1 12400 1432 ?      S   Aug15 0:00 /bin/bash /home/user/start-cacheable.bash
user 1327 0.0 0.3 12744 2254 tty1   S   Aug15 0:00 -bash
```

Now from here, I'd run `kill 1031 1032`. Is there a clean command that could get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jjlin answer might work.

But to explain the working of `pgrep/pkill` and `killall`:

killall looks for **process names** only - that's the part seen in `/proc/<pid>/comm`

pgrep/pkill does by default the same, but can also look for a match in arguments too (-f), which makes it match agains `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`

Basically, by default only strings seen in `ps -A` are considered.

example:

```
process name (comm): sshd
full command/arguments (cmdline): /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

now - `kilall/pkil sshd` would work (intentional typos, don't do it ;)
but `killall /usr/sbin/sshd` would **NOT work** because the path is not part of the process name
you can check with `pgrep -lf sshd_config` (i.e. pkill -f)

Then, here are other things to consider. `Killall` might be matching only on the first 15 bytes of a command name (see `killall -e`), whether regular expressions are needed, or you want to leverage process groups etc.

note: the /proc/... files are null-delimited, so watch out during copy/paste

Comment: Your explanation got me there. I ran `pgrep -lf bash` and found the process is called just `start-cacheable`. Putting a `pkill` in front of it does the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
ps aux | grep <your keyword> | grep -v grep | awk  '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Lists matching process(es), filters out the grep process itself, grabs the PID, passes it to kill -9.

Test before you use the kill -9

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pkill start-cacheable.bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
killall <process name>
```

Comment: That's where I went, but it's not acting as I hoped. If I run `killall "/bin/bash /home/user/start-cacheable.bash"` it doesn't do anything. What's the process name exactly?

Comment: @mjb It's the (executable) image name. Arguments are not included.